# Download files with acclist not working as excpected

Tags: wget

I want to download all files matching a certain pattern from https://download.osmand.net/list.php.

For example running

```
wget -nd -r -A 'list.php, *Sweden_*' https://download.osmand.net/list.php
```

downloads only `list.php`.

If I use

```
wget -nd -r -A 'list.php, *' https://download.osmand.net/list.php
```

instead all files are downloaded.

What is wrong with my acclist in the first example?

Comment: Why the `php` tag? How php is involved in this question?

Comment: The tag was automatically suggested. Since the URL in question points to a php file I added the tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't know myself, researching for this answer I learned something new.

[wget docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Recursive-Accept_002fReject-Options.html#Recursive-Accept_002fReject-Options) says:

> **‘-A acclist --accept acclist’**
>   ‘**-R rejlist --reject rejlist’**
>   Specify comma-separated lists of file name suffixes or patterns to accept or reject (see Types of Files). Note that if any of the wildcard characters, ‘*’, ‘?’, ‘[’ or ‘]’, appear in an element of acclist or rejlist, it will be treated as a pattern, rather than a suffix. In this case, you have to enclose the pattern into quotes to prevent your shell from expanding it, like in ‘-A "*.mp3"’ or ‘-A '*.mp3'’.
>
> **‘--accept-regex urlregex’**
>   **‘--reject-regex urlregex’**
>   Specify a regular expression to accept or reject the complete URL.

So it seems that `-A` can be used to check extensions, but not the full pattern of the link. To search the full pattern, you need the `--accept-regex urlregex` option.

The following command worked for me.

```
wget -nd -r --accept-regex 'Sweden_' https://download.osmand.net/list.php
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks